# How to use OFFSET and FETCH after ORDER BY DESC?

Tags: sql, postgresql, spring-boot, jpa

This query works on my database:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM notes
WHERE owner='69177f5e-a6d3-4ad9-b609-dd02586cb589'
ORDER BY creation_date DESC
OFFSET 1 ROWS FETCH NEXT 2 ROWS ONLY;
```

And I would like to write it in my JPA Repository in `@Query` but I can't continue writing the query after `DESC` because IntelliJ underlines `OFFSET` and shows me `',' or NULLS expected, got 'OFFSET'`. What can I do in this situation. Is similar query possible to do using Spring Boot JPA? 
Thanks so much.

Comment: I guess you are writing native query but #pagable object is missing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Query("SELECT n from Notes n where n.owner='69177f5e-a6d3-4ad9-b609-dd02586cb589' ORDER BY n.creationDate DESC")
public Page<Notes> findAllByOwner(Pageable pageable);
```

This is pseudo code so you have to fill necessary fields creation_date and owner fields has to match with entity fields

Comment: And JPA will sort under the hood using `Pageable` argument and result will be same like using normal SQL query (like in my question)?

Comment: yes you are right you have to specify your pageable object according to limit and offset.

Comment: Okay. I've used it and everything works. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could just use a `LIMIT` HQL query here:

```java
@Query("SELECT * FROM notes WHERE owner = '69177f5e-a6d3-4ad9-b609-dd02586cb589' ORDER BY creation_date DESC LIMIT 3")
List<Note> findAllOwners();
```

This would return an (ordered) list containing only *three* items.  Since you want an offset of 1, just access the last *two* items for your desired result set.

Specifically, if you call this repository method, you can try:

```java
List<Note> allOwners = yourInterface.findAllOwners();
allOwners.remove(0);  // this is now your desired result set
```